# Which makes more sense when calling myself a fool / foolish?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference, phrase

A girl that I like frequently calls me 笨蛋. I want to confess my feelings to her and wasn't sure if saying 我知道我很笨蛋。 or 我知道我是笨蛋。makes more sense gramatically.

Answer (score 1):

[笨蛋](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%AC%A8%E8%9B%8B) is a noun (a person who is silly), while [笨](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%AC%A8) is an adjective, so you'd want one of these:

> 我知道我很**笨**，……  [很 + adjective]
> 我知道我是（个）**笨蛋**，……  [是 + noun]

Presumably you'd want the latter to echo your romantic interest's wording.

I don't believe it's grammatically correct to say 我很笨蛋 since 很 would normally be [followed by an adjective](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Simple_%22noun_%2B_adjective%22_sentences) (or something functioning as an adjective).

Answer (score 0):

I consulted the God Cupid, his Chinese is good, for a Greek!

我知道我很笨，不善于表达自己的感情，但是我是真心话你。你可以做为我的女朋友吗？

真心话你：真心喜欢你

In the name of love,
One man in the name of love!

Good luck! Let me know what she says!